# Find all real number root sum of squares$\left(\frac{x^3+x}{3}\right)^3+\frac{x^3+x}{3}=3x$

Tags: polynomials

Find sum of the squares of all real roots? 
$$\left(\dfrac{x^3+x}{3}\right)^3+\dfrac{x^3+x}{3}=3x$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E3%2Bx%2F3)%5E3%2B(x%5E3%2Bx)%2F3%3D3x) give three real roots, I known $x=0$ is one of them.  But why only have other two real roots?

The key is to find which roots are real and which are complex?

Comment: When is this due?

Comment: Hint: $f(x) = \frac13(x^3+x)$ is strictly increasing in $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the system
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}y=\frac{x^3+x}3\\y^3+y=3x\end{array}\right.$$
or
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}x^3+x=3y\\y^3+y=3x\end{array}\right.$$
Substract
$$(x^3-y^3)+(x-y)+3(x-y)=0\qquad (*)$$
If $x=y$ then
$$x^3-2x=0$$
Therefore $x=0$, $x=\sqrt 2$ and $x=-\sqrt 2$ are three solutions.
If $x\neq y$ we can divide the equation $(*)$ by $x-y$ to obtain
$$x^2+xy+y^2=-4$$

Since $y=(x^3+x)/3$,
$$x^2+\frac{x^4+x^2}3+\frac{x^6+2x^4+x^2}9=-4$$
which has no real roots. Note that all the terms in LHS are non negative.

Comment: Thanks,since $x^2+xy+y^2\ge \dfrac{3y^2}{4}>0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\dfrac{x^3+x}{3}$, then $y^3+y=3x$

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    x^3+x &= 3y \quad \cdots \cdots \quad (1) \\
    y^3+y &= 3x \quad \cdots \cdots \quad (2)
  \end{align*}
\right.$$

Sum and difference of $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2-2) &= 0 \\
    (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+4) &= 0
  \end{align*}
\right.$$

- If $x+y=0$, then $x^3+4x=0 \implies x(x^2+4)=0$
- If $x-y=0$, then $x^3-2x=0 \implies x(x^2-2)=0$
- If $x^2\ne y^2$, then $x^2+y^2+1=0$ and $xy=-3$

**Can you proceed?**